# How can I add an ember.js partial to a template?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

What I am trying to do below is using partials to make my views more modular. Unfortunately this does not work.

I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'view' of undefined in the (compiled) _dataForLeftPane.js @ the following line,
  stack1 = foundHelper ? foundHelper.call(depth0, stack1, {hash:{}}) : helperMissing.call(depth0, "outlet", stack1, {hash:{}});
```

If I get remove the partials declared in container.hjs (see the code below) and put their respective contents instead, everything works. But only when I introduce partials, things stop working.

```
file: app_router.js.coffee

root: Ember.Route.extend(
  index: Ember.Route.extend(
    route: '/'
    connectOutlets: (router) ->
      router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('container')
      router.get('containerController').connectOutlet('dataForLeftPane', 'dataForLeftPane', [{login:'wycats'},{login:'tomdale'}])
      router.get('containerController').connectOutlet('dataForRightPane', 'dataForRightPane', [{id:'1234'},{id:'qwerty'}])
  )
)
```

```
file: views/application_view.js.coffee

App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.extend(
  templateName: 'application'
)

App.ContainerView = Ember.View.extend(
  templateName: 'a/container'
)

App.DataForLeftPaneView = Ember.View.extend(
  templateName: 'a/dataForLeftPane'
)

App.DataForRightPaneView = Ember.View.extend(
  templateName: 'a/dataForRightPane'
)
```

```
file: templates/a/container.hjs

{{> _a_leftPane}}
{{> _a_rightPane}}
```

```
file: templates/a/_leftPane.hbs

{{outlet dataForLeftPane}}
```

```
file: templates/a/_rightPane.hbs

{{outlet dataForRightPane}}
```

```
file: templates/a/dataForRightPane.hjs

{{#each person in controller}}
  {{person.id}}
{{/each}}
```

```
file: templates/a/dataForLeftPane.hjs

{{#each person in controller}}
  {{person.name}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can 'call' a view with the [view helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_view) inside another template.

```
file: templates/parentView.hjs
{{view.someProperty}}
//here is the parent view calling a template
{{view "App.templateView" contentBinding="view.content"}}
```

This will insert the specified App.templateView with a content binding to the passed content property of the rendered view. You can pass any content you want as the templateViews content.

This is most likely what you want to do but I am not sure if I read your question correctly.

Also this is semantically close to rendering a partial in rails with a passed local. So I think that might be the solution you are looking for since you were referring to 'partial'.